# Check for a value in XML in Oracle BI Publisher 11g

Tags: xml, oracle, xslt, bi-publisher

Below is my xml sample.  Here's what I want

1. Loop through all cars
2. If a car has a "Sport" style then display them, otherwise, ignore it

So in the example below, I will display Ferrari and 2 values of Convertible and Sport

I have `<for-each>Car</end-for-each>`.  I want to check if a car has a style of "Sport" or not.  How do I do that?  Do I have to have another `<for-each>Style</end-for-each>` inside the `<for-each>Car</end-for-each>`?  If I found a sport style then I'm initializing a variable and assign it such as

```
<?xdoxslt:set_variable($_XDOCTX, ’car’, 1)?> --- initialize to 1 if Sport style found
<?xdoxslt:get_variable($_XDOCTX, ’car’)?> --- retrieve

<Car>
<Brand>Honda</Brand>
<Style>Coupe</Style>
<Style>Sedan</Style>
</Car>
<Car>
<Brand>Ferrari</Brand>
<Style>Convertible</Style>
<Style>Sport</Style>
</Car>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here's what I want
>
> 1. Loop through all cars
> 2. If a car has a "Sport" style then display them, otherwise, ignore it

Normally, in XSLT you would approach this problem as:

1. Select all cars with a "Sport" style;
2. Display them.

For example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Car[Style='Sport']">
    <!-- whatever "display" means -->
</xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively, if "display" is the default for all nodes (e.g. if you're applying the *identity transform template*) you could apply an empty template matching all cars that do **not** have a "Sport" style, in order to suppress them.